# List: Find the first index and count the occurrence of a specific list in list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

we have a variable named location.

```
location=[["world", 'Live'], ["alpha",'Live'], ['hello', 'Scheduled'],['alpha', 'Live'], ['just', 'Live'], ['alpha','Scheduled'], ['alpha', 'Live']]
```

i want to find the first index and count occurrence of **list["alpha",'Live']** in location.
i tried the following:

```
index= [location.index(i) for i in location if i ==["alpha", 'Live'] ]
count = [location.count(i) for i in location if i ==["alpha",'Live'] ]
print('index',index)
print('count', count)
```

this returns:
index [1, 1, 1]
count [3, 3, 3]

but is there a way to find both **first index, count** simultaneously using list comprehension.

**expected output:**

index, count = 1, 3

Comment: what does the expected output look like?

Comment: Do you mean `index, count = location.index(['alpha', 'Live']), location.count(['alpha', 'Live'])` ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Was about to write that, you should add an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

does this solve you problem?

```
location=[["world", 'Live'], ["alpha",'Live'], ['hello', 'Scheduled'],['alpha', 'Live'], ['just', 'Live'], ['alpha','Scheduled'], ['alpha', 'Live']]
index= location.index(["alpha",'Live'])
count = location.count(["alpha",'Live'])
print('index',index)
print('count', count)
```

if `['alpha','live']` is not found, find the first `['alpha',??]` and print its index and count.

```
location = [["world", 'Live'], ["alpha", 'Live'], ['hello', 'Scheduled'], [
    'alpha', 'Live'], ['just', 'Live'], ['alpha', 'Scheduled'], ['alpha', 'Live']]

key = ["alpha", 'Lsive']

count = location.count(key)

if count:
    index = location.index(key)
    print('count', count)
    print('index', index)
else:
    for i in location:
        if i[0] == key[0]:
            key = i
            count = location.count(key)
            index = location.index(key)
            print('count', count)
            print('index', index)
    else:
        print('not found')
```

cleaner code by @yadavender yadav

```
location = [["alpha", 'Scheduled'], ["alpha", 'Live'], ['hello', 'Scheduled'], [
    'alpha', 'Live'], ['just', 'Live'], ['alpha', 'Scheduled'], ['alpha', 'Live']]

key = ["alpha", 'Scheduled']

count = location.count(key)

if count:
    index = location.index(key)
else:
    index=[location.index(i) for i in location if i[0]=="alpha"][0]
print('count', count)
print('index', index)
```

Comment: i guess i was just trying to be fancy with list comprehension.Thanks!

Comment: nothing wrong with being fancy :), make sure to mark the correct answer for future references.

Comment: Followup doubt: if there is no ["alpha",'Live'] then how can we return index of ["alpha",'Scheduled'] instead.

anything better than this:
```
try:
    print(something.index(['yadutest616', 'Live']))
except ValueError:
    print(something.index(['yadutest616', 'Scheduled']))
```

Comment: @yadavenderyadav, you are 100% right, i'll edit my code.

Comment: let me frame the question again.
if not ["alpha",'Live'] then find index of ["alpha", anything]

without using
try: print(location.index(['alpha', 'Live'])) except ValueError: print(location.index(['alpha', 'Scheduled']))

Comment: edited sorry for the delay.

Comment: i think in **else** we can use something like :
`index=[location.index(i) for i in location if i[0]=="alpha"][0]`

Comment: you have outdone me :), very smart and fancy.